# Is it okay to vote for just two candidates?

Tags: support, voting, moderator-election

Is it within the voting rules to just pick two candidates as the first and second choice?

That is, is a third choice required in order for the vote to be valid?

I searched 5 or 6 suggested relevant questions, but I couldn't find this one duplicated.

Comment: I can't envision a situation in which your vote isn't *valid* if you only vote for one candidate.

Comment: I tried to read about STV, Meek and Single, and sort-of-kind-of followed the logic.  I just want to make sure that I stick with the rule book (even though I don't understand it)

Comment: Very possibly, yes.

Comment: You _can_ use as few of your votes as you like, but make sure you also understand than using more votes **does not weaken** the strength of your vote(s) for more preference candidates. Only is the event that 100% of your 1st vote is either not enough to elect or not needed to elect will the 2nd even be looked at, and so on. Not using the 3rd vote only makes sense if you have absolutely no preference between all 8 remaining candidates.

Comment: No, you will ruin everything.  Obviously.

Comment: @Will  Bwahahaa !!  I'm going to ruin the entire system; and bring down the whole internet

Comment: Us statisticians over at CrossValidated had the [exact same question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/using-all-votes-in-elections?noredirect=1#comment6892_2483). Naturally the answers were accompanied by a statistical analysis of our recent moderation results to indicate that: yes users who did not use all their votes were included in the election.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Is it *ok*? Sure. You can vote for as few candidates as you like. You can vote for none of them if that's what suits you.

You can select up to three candidates, but you're under no obligation to select three. STV voting is pretty flexible that way.

You should vote for any and all of the candidates you feel would make suitable moderators, or the three you feel would be *most* suitable if there are more than three you would be OK with.

Note though that if you only select two and both of your candidates are eliminated, your opinion will no longer contribute to the selection of a winner. So unless there are only two candidates that you'd be comfortable with winning, you should try to select a third.

#### See also: [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)

Comment: Personally, I never see any of these candidates around. The only person I've seen is Martijn Peters - Him being the only person I've voted for in the election, because he's the only person I've ever seen being helpful (or really, the only person out of the candidates that I have ever seen at all!).

Comment: @Joehot200 You need to hang around more then.

Comment: @ZachSaucier This is the problem with StackOverflow though! I come here to ask a question about ArrayLists hanging my program, and an hour later I am still browsing through meta posts and elections without having asked my question yet!

Comment: Is it actually possible to *'vote for none of them'* in a way that is distinct from not voting at all? I.e. is it possible to submit a blank ballot, or cast a vote for 'none of the above'?

Comment: @HugoRune As far as I know that's not possible at the moment. Perhaps it's time for a feature request?